# Add tracing to all methods of class in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Spring Boot microservice. To find a source of latency problem I need to add tracing to some objects. `zipking` is already configurated so I want to add custom span.

Imagine that I have a class with 20 methods that makes database calls. To add my span I do something like this

```
@Repository
public class myClass {

    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;

    public int myMethod1(){
        Span span = tracer.createSpan("dbcall");
        try{
            // initial method content here
        } finally {
            tracer.close(span);
        }            
    }

    public int myMethod2(){
         // the same as above  
    }

    // .......

    public int myMethod20(){
         // the same as above  
    }
}
```

Any ideas about a smarter way to do it without copypasting `try/finally` and `span` init hundreds of times?

Comment: AOP definitely the right tool here

Comment: You can do this with aspect-oriented programming, which Spring supports (in a limited way). I don't have the time right now to explain it in detail - look it up in the Spring documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for comments to my question, as suggested I implemented it with AOP. 
Here is my solution, it will be probably useful for somebody.

Add AOP dependency to `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I created custom attribute `TrackLatency.java`

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrackLatency {
    String value() default "Track Latency Span";
}
```

Than I added the aspect that adds span to every method with attribute call

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CreateNewSpanMethodAspect {
    private final Tracer tracer;

    @Around("@annotation(classpath.TrackLatency)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
        Span span = tracer.createSpan(getTrackLatencyAnnotationValue(call));
        try{
             return call.proceed();
        } finally {
            tracer.close(span);
        }
     }

     private static String getTrackLatencyAnnotationValue(ProceedingJoinPoint call){
         MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) call.getSignature();
         Method method = signature.getMethod();
         TrackLatency trackLatencyAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(TrackLatency.class);
         return trackLatencyAnnotation.value();
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
@TrackLatency("dbCall: myDbCall")
public List<QuestionAnswerRow> myDbCall(....) {
    // no changes in my repository
}
```